# ExtJS 4.1: MessageBox 4 buttons

Tags: extjs4

I'm trying to have 4 buttons for a closable `MessageBox` and realized that the close(x) button is invoking my 4th button's custom function instead of closing the dialog.

here is my button config:

```
{
  ok      : 'Action1',
  yes     : 'Action2',
  no      : 'Action3', 
  cancel  : 'Action4'
}
```

handler code:

```
fn : function(buttonId, text, option) {
switch (buttonId)
    {
        case 'ok' :
            action1();
            break ;
        case 'yes' :
            action2();
            break ;
        case 'no' :
            action3();
            break ;
        case 'cancel' :
            action4();
            break ;                                         
    }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: You need more code.  What is your selector for the triggered function(s)?

Comment: Why would you need both YES and OK? If you don't really need them, use  this: http://docs-origin.sencha.com/ext/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.window.MessageBox-property-YESNOCANCEL

Comment: @Saki, by using  `YESNOCANCEL`, I'm getting only 3 buttons, but I need 4 buttons

Comment: @C.Parcell, updated the orignal question with the handler code.

Comment: By default ExtJS uses 3 buttons, if you need more create new window with 4 buttons and with message. I'll give you answer with picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the way for solve your problem. I created new window with 4 buttons as default YESNOCANCEL window.

[image]

Here's code of window:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyWindow', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

requires: [
    'Ext.container.Container',
    'Ext.Img',
    'Ext.form.Label',
    'Ext.button.Button'
],

autoShow: true,
border: false,
height: 165,
width: 329,
title: 'Save Changes?',

layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    align: 'stretch'
},

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                flex: 3,
                margin: 5,
                layout: {
                    type: 'hbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'image',
                        flex: 1,
                        height: 86,
                        padding: 15,
                        width: 113,
                        src: 'icon-question.png'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        flex: 3,
                        padding: '15 10 5 10',
                        text: 'You are closing a tab that has unsaved changes. Would you like to save your changes?'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                flex: 2,
                padding: '10 5 10 5',
                layout: {
                    type: 'hbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        flex: 1,
                        margin: '0 5 0 0',
                        text: 'Yes'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        flex: 1,
                        margin: '0 5 0 0',
                        text: 'No'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        flex: 1,
                        margin: '0 5 0 0',
                        text: 'New Button'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        flex: 1,
                        text: 'Cancel'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});